# How do I combine the html, css, and javascript code into one document from a jsfiddle?

Tags: html

This is probably really dumb but someone recommended this fiddle to me

http://goo.gl/Fgmwjj

and I want to test it out but I want to write it in Notepad++ the only thing is I don't know the right syntax to combine all three languages into one document.

Answer (score 7):

Add `<script>` tags to include a script. For something you need loaded AFTER the HTML, load it at the bottom before your `</body>`.

Add a `<style>` tag inside your `head` to include `CSS`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#textin {
    width: 500px;
    height: 150px;
}
#textout {
    font-family: courier;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 40em;
    height: 200px;
    resize: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<form>
    <textarea id="textin" name="myText"></textarea>
    <br/>
    <br/>Cost:
    <input type="text" name="lineCount" size="1" value="0" />Dollars
    <br/>
    <br/>Formatted:
    <br/>
    <textarea id="textout" name="formatText" disabled="yes"></textarea>
</form>

<script>
function countLines() {
    var theArea = document.getElementById("textin");
    var theLines = theArea.value;
    theLines = theLines.split("\n");
    var finalLines = [];

    var numLines = theLines.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < numLines; i++) {
        if (theLines[i].length > 40) {
            if(theLines[i].match(/^.{0,38}\S{41}/)) {
                theLines[i] = theLines[i].replace(/^(.{40})/, "$1\n");
                var newLines = [i,1].concat(theLines[i].split("\n"));
                numLines++;
                Array.prototype.splice.apply(theLines, newLines);
            } else {
                theLines[i] = theLines[i].replace(/(.{1,40}[^\S\n])/, "$1\n");
                var newLines = [i,1].concat(theLines[i].split("\n"));
                numLines++;
                Array.prototype.splice.apply(theLines, newLines);
            }
        }
        finalLines.push(theLines[i]);
    }

    while (finalLines.length && finalLines[finalLines.length - 1].match(/^\s*$/)) {
        finalLines.pop();
    }

    theArea.form.lineCount.value = finalLines.length;

    document.getElementById("textout").value = finalLines.join("\n");
}

var el = document.getElementById("textin");
if (el.addEventListener) {
    el.addEventListener("input", countLines, false);
} else {
    el.attachEvent('onpropertychange', countLines);
    el.attachEvent('onkeypress', countLines);
}

var observe;
if (window.attachEvent) {
    observe = function (element, event, handler) {
        element.attachEvent('on' + event, handler);
    };
} else {
    observe = function (element, event, handler) {
        element.addEventListener(event, handler, false);
    };
}

function init() {
    var text = document.getElementById('text');

    function resize() {
        text.style.height = 'auto';
        text.style.height = text.scrollHeight + 'px';
    }
    /* 0-timeout to get the already changed text */
    function delayedResize() {
        window.setTimeout(resize, 0);
    }
    observe(text, 'change', resize);
    observe(text, 'cut', delayedResize);
    observe(text, 'paste', delayedResize);
    observe(text, 'drop', delayedResize);
    observe(text, 'keydown', delayedResize);

    text.focus();
    text.select();
    resize();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you feel this is an acceptable answer, please mark it as such with the `green checkbox` near the voting option.

Answer (score 6):

Jsfiddle uses HTML, CSS and JavaScript to render the final result. Both CSS and JS can be easily embedded into an HTML document using `<style>` and `<script>` tags respectively. You would be looking at something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            CSS goes here
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            JS goes here
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        HTML goes here
    </body>
</html>
```

It's usually best to put your CSS/JS in external files then link them so the browser can cache them, among other reasons, but embedded works in a pinch.

Comment: 100% Agree. This is a solution for quick testing, but your end-case should load external files for `CSS` and `JS`.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't even look at the code but I just put it together for you, hopefully this gets you started :)

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#textin {
    width: 500px;
    height: 150px;
}
#textout {
    font-family: courier;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 40em;
    height: 200px;
    resize: none;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function countLines() {
    var theArea = document.getElementById("textin");
    var theLines = theArea.value;
    theLines = theLines.split("\n");
    var finalLines = [];

    var numLines = theLines.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < numLines; i++) {
        if (theLines[i].length > 40) {
            if(theLines[i].match(/^.{0,38}\S{41}/)) {
                theLines[i] = theLines[i].replace(/^(.{40})/, "$1\n");
                var newLines = [i,1].concat(theLines[i].split("\n"));
                numLines++;
                Array.prototype.splice.apply(theLines, newLines);
            } else {
                theLines[i] = theLines[i].replace(/(.{1,40}[^\S\n])/, "$1\n");
                var newLines = [i,1].concat(theLines[i].split("\n"));
                numLines++;
                Array.prototype.splice.apply(theLines, newLines);
            }
        }
        finalLines.push(theLines[i]);
    }

    while (finalLines.length && finalLines[finalLines.length - 1].match(/^\s*$/)) {
        finalLines.pop();
    }

    theArea.form.lineCount.value = finalLines.length;

    document.getElementById("textout").value = finalLines.join("\n");
}

var el = document.getElementById("textin");
if (el.addEventListener) {
    el.addEventListener("input", countLines, false);
} else {
    el.attachEvent('onpropertychange', countLines);
    el.attachEvent('onkeypress', countLines);
}

var observe;
if (window.attachEvent) {
    observe = function (element, event, handler) {
        element.attachEvent('on' + event, handler);
    };
} else {
    observe = function (element, event, handler) {
        element.addEventListener(event, handler, false);
    };
}

function init() {
    var text = document.getElementById('text');

    function resize() {
        text.style.height = 'auto';
        text.style.height = text.scrollHeight + 'px';
    }
    /* 0-timeout to get the already changed text */
    function delayedResize() {
        window.setTimeout(resize, 0);
    }
    observe(text, 'change', resize);
    observe(text, 'cut', delayedResize);
    observe(text, 'paste', delayedResize);
    observe(text, 'drop', delayedResize);
    observe(text, 'keydown', delayedResize);

    text.focus();
    text.select();
    resize();
}
</script>

<body>

<form>
    <textarea id="textin" name="myText"></textarea>
    <br/>
    <br/>Cost:
    <input type="text" name="lineCount" size="1" value="0" />Dollars
    <br/>
    <br/>Formatted:
    <br/>
    <textarea id="textout" name="formatText" disabled="yes"></textarea>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your copy-paste skills are no joke, sir.